# Ajax JSON request always goes to .fail callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

It always goes to .fail path.. Even if the PHP file is just  or print null;

This is the code I have now.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/getValues.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { clickedId: "clickedId" },
   })
.done(function(datos){
  alert("OK");
  $("#titulo").val(datos.titulo);
  $("#precio").val(datos.precio);
})
.fail(function() {
  alert("fail");

})

})
```

PHP request:

```
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','clarodeluna');

    $id=$_POST['clickedId'];
    $sql = "SELECT titulo, precio FROM coleccion WHERE id=$id";

    $result=$con->query($sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $titulo = $row['titulo'];
        $precio = $row['precio'];

        $datos = array(
            "titulo" => $titulo,
            "precio" => $precio,    
            )
    };


    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print json_encode($datos);
```

If I change dataType from json to html it doesnt go to .fail callback function.. So i guess its has to be with the JSON format, but i repeat, if i just write print null or print {} in the php file it stills with the fail

Comment: what happens if you put the `header` function on top of the `print`?

Comment: Have you inspected the `errorThrown` (3rd argument passed to `fail()` callbacks by `$.ajax()`) or the actual response provided by the request (can be seen under "Network" in your browser's dev tools)? Best guess is that the `header()` needs to be set before `print`ing any output.

Comment: @AlexAndrei Stills the same. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it!

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/getValues.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { clickedId: "clickedId" }, **THIS WAS WRONG!**
   })
```

Should be

```
data: { "clickedId": clickedId }
```

Thank you all!

Comment: that was only one of numerous problems

Comment: Yes.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax problem as well as you can't set a header after you output anything

Most likely you are currently seeing a 500 error status if you inspect the request in browser dev tools network

Try changing to following:

```
  $datos = array(
        "titulo" => $titulo;
        "precio" => $precio;    
        );// added `;`

header('Content-Type: application/json');// header before output
echo json_encode($datos);
```

This all assumes that `clickedId` is properly defined in your ajax data

Use browser dev tools to inspect actual request as first line of debugging to see status, what is sent/returned etc

Comment: Hi, I corrected the syntax errors but it stills go to fail callback function.
If i change dataType from json to html it goes to .done

Comment: then inspect the actual request to see what is sent and what status is and what is in response body. Just saying it goes to fail is not very meaningful

Comment: That's the problem.. I just don't get it how can I debug this. In the chrome console it doesn't throw any error line..

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't know that.
I checked but the php request has no syntax errors

Comment: note that `.done(function(){` is missing data argument ==> `.done(function(datos){..`